# Aria2c - how to download a lot of files and ouput as 0.pdf, 1.pdf, 2.pdf ...?

Tags: terminal, download, aria2

I'm having a little problem here. I'm using the famous Aria2C file downloader and I have a list of links that I need to download. I know I can use:

```
aria2c -o myOutputFile.exe http://www.fooBar.com/fooBarVirus.exe
```

to download a single file and name it as `myOutputFile.exe`. The problem is that **I must** download some files and name it as 0.pdf, 1.pdf, 2.pdf, 3.pdf... because I will assemble all this pdf's later.

**I'll try explain better. If I give the following links to aria2c:**

```
http://www.fooBar.com/myPDF.pdf
http://www.fooBar.com/kindness.pdf
http://www.fooBar.com/crazyPdf.pdf
...
http://www.fooBar.com/myLastPdf.pdf
```

**I must** download these files and name it as a sequence of integers FOLLOWING THE LINKS INSERTION ORDER. With that I mean the filenames is related to the links order, but **I don't need to download them in order**.

Let's suppose I give Aria2C the previous links. The following output would be a valid output for my problem:

```
 Time: 0
 Link: http://www.fooBar.com/crazyPdf.pdf
 Filename: 2.pdf

 Time: 1
 Link: http://www.fooBar.com/myPDF.pdf
 Filename: 0.pdf

 Time: 2
 Link: http://www.fooBar.com/kindness.pdf
 Filename: 1.pdf

 ...

 Time: N
 Link: http://www.fooBar.com/myLastPdf.pdf
 Filename: N.pdf
```

I know this is a confusing question, so if you have any doubt please make a comment and I'll try answer as soon as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Ok, let's start with a `pdfs.txt` file holding the URLs for the PDFs:

```
http://www.fooBar.com/myPDF.pdf
http://www.fooBar.com/kindness.pdf
http://www.fooBar.com/crazyPdf.pdf
http://www.fooBar.com/myLastPdf.pdf
```

I throw in a little helper script to turn the URLs from the `pdfs.txt` file into the file format Aria2c accepts. The script uses the numerical index of an URL in the array as the new filename for the PDF.

```
<?php
$urls = __DIR__ . '/pdfs.txt';
$downloads = file($urls);

$targetFolder = __DIR__; // define your taget folder
$ariaDownloadList = '';
foreach($downloads as $idx => $url)
{
    $pdfName = $idx . '.pdf'; // 0.pdf ... N.pdf

    // add new download entry
    $ariaDownloadList .= $url;
    $ariaDownloadList .= '  dir=' . pathinfo($targetFolder, PATHINFO_DIRNAME) . PHP_EOL;
    $ariaDownloadList .= '  out=' . $pdfName . PHP_EOL;
}

file_put_contents('ariaDownloadsFile.txt', $ariaDownloadList);
```

This outputs a file `ariaDownloadsFile.txt` with the following content:

```
http://www.fooBar.com/myPDF.pdf
  dir=C:\pdfs
  out=0.pdf
http://www.fooBar.com/kindness.pdf
  dir=C:\pdfs
  out=1.pdf
http://www.fooBar.com/crazyPdf.pdf
  dir=C:\pdfs
  out=2.pdf
http://www.fooBar.com/myLastPdf.pdf  
  dir=C:\pdfs
  out=3.pdf
```

Then simply run the following command:

```
aria2c -i ariaDownloadsFile.txt
```